# ClassCastException in Oracle Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, jpa, weblogic12c, classcastexception

I'm developing several Java Enterprise Applications that run on a Weblogic 12c server, and am encountering a ClassCastException due to what seems to be a class loader issue.

I have 2 EAR files: ApplicationA.ear and ApplicationB.ear.

Both applications require access to the same database. Both ear files have a jar packaged that contains a service class (stateless session bean) which uses a DAO class, which uses JPA (entity manager, persistence.xml, etc.) to retrieve data from the database. Pretty basic stuff. Each individual ear file runs fine by itself, but when both applications run on the same node (or in this case the AdminServer), a ClassCastException regularly occurs.

The ClassCastException says that my JPA entity class MyEntity cannot be cast to MyEntity. But it's the same class in both ear files.

I suspect Weblogic somehow uses classloader A from ApplicationA and uses classloader B from ApplicationB, and it looks like that whomever uses the service first will win. The other application will result in the ClassCastException when the service is used.

Does anyone know a solution or workaround for this issue? Or maybe even knows why the problem is occurring?

We've tried turning off 2nd level cache in EclipseLink, but that did not help unfortunately. Spreading the ear files over multiple nodes works, but we would prefer not to go there due to extra configuration being required.

Comment: Hey can you try adding "serialVersionUID" to your class? ie; Both class with the same "serialVersionUID" - which helps JVM identify that both are from same class.. Hope it helps..

Comment: Apologies for the late response. Unfortunately that did not help.

Comment: Can you try implementing `Serializable` interface for your class? And If possible can you please setup a reproducible environment, just to see what's happening?

Comment: I've given it a go, but so far I have not been able to reproduce the error with a small example project. I'll give it some more effort soon to see if I can reproduce it, and otherwise I will start stripping down my real application to see when the problem disappears. Cheers so far for the responses.

Comment: Yeah sure lftl.